# Finding the inverse of a (challenging) function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, differential-topology, elementary-functions

I just started reading *Differential Topology* by Guillemin and Pollak and one of the very first exercises is the following:

> Let $B_a$ be the open ball $\{x : \vert x \vert ^2 < a \}$ in
>   $\mathbb{R}^k$. $\left(\vert x \vert^2 = \sum x_i^2\right)$.   Show
>   that the map $$ x \mapsto \frac{ax}{\sqrt{a^2-\vert x \vert^2}}$$
>
> is a diffeomorphism of $B_a$ onto $\mathbb{R}^k$. Hint: Compute its
>   inverse directly.

I tried different ways to compute the inverse mapping but unfortunately without success.

My very first naive approach was writing it as $$ y = \frac{ax}{\sqrt{a^2-\vert x \vert^2}}$$ and trying to get $x$ separated. Didnt manage to do so. My next attempt was by using the composition $f(f^{-1}(x)) = x$ to get the identity but that attempt did not succeed either.

I am clearly missing something. Can anyone help me with a few hints or tell me the secret of finding the inverse mapping?

Comment: Note there's a typo in the problem. It should be $\{x: |x|<a\}$. [If you go to my webpage linked in my profile, you will find a link to download a list of errata for Guillemin and Pollack.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the scalar case. Then we see that
\begin{align}
|y|^2= \frac{a^2|x|^2}{a^2-|x|^2} \ \ \implies \ \ |x|=\frac{a|y|}{\sqrt{a^2+|y|^2}}.
\end{align}
Hence an appropriate candiate is given by
\begin{align}
f^{-1}(y) = \frac{ay}{\sqrt{a^2+|y|^2}}.
\end{align}

Indeed, by direct calculation we see that
\begin{align}
f^{-1}(f(x)) = f^{-1}\left( \frac{ax}{\sqrt{a^2-|x|^2}}\right) = \frac{a^2x}{\sqrt{a^2-|x|^2}}\left(a^2+\frac{a^2|x|^2}{a^2-|x|^2}\right)^{-1/2} =y.
\end{align}

Comment: oh wow! that was pretty enlightening, i seem to have done a few mistakes in my very first attempt which led me to not being able to get to the solution myself. thank you very much for that detailed answer. highly appreciating it.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would separate the scalars from the vectors:

$$
f(x) = \frac a {\sqrt{a^2 - |x|^2}} x
$$

Notice that this function just scales $x$: it doesn't change the "direction" of $x$, only its magnitude.

In particular, it maps magnitudes $m \to m'$ as

$$
m'(m) = \frac {am} {\sqrt{a^2 - m^2}}
$$

Inverting the above function is straightforward; that will tell you how to "undo" the scaling of the original function. By plugging in the inverse $m$ map into something like the following, you would get your overall inverse:

$$
f^{-1}(x) = \frac {m(|x|)} {|x|} x
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the case when $x$ and $y$ are scalars.

The trick to finding the inverse of $y=f(x)$ is to write $x=f(y)$.  So, $$x= \frac{ay}{\sqrt{a^2-{\mid y\mid}^2}}$$.  Now solve for $y$ in terms of $x$...

Get $$x^2=\frac{a^2y^2}{a^2-{\mid y\mid}^2}$$.  So, $$x^2=\frac{a^2y^2}{a^2-y^2}\implies x^2(a^2-y^2)=a^2y^2\implies a^2x^2=(a^2+x^2)y^2\implies y=\frac{ax}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}\implies y=\frac{ax}{\sqrt{a^2+{\mid x\mid}^2}}$$ is our inverse. You should check it...